# Nuxt 3 app with tailwind css how to edit the main body element?

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

I am learning VueJS with the help of NuxtJS and Tailwindcss for a hobby project.
Since tailwindcss makes it really easy to edit for darkmode i ran in to a problem on the safari browser.

Whenever you scroll or drag the browser in darkmode down or up, you always see a white background. This is the body and i cannot change it.

What i have tried is to add Body tag in to my main app VueJS file where i combine my components to build the page. But this results in a Body tag inside the Main app Div.
That would mean that i have two body tags like this

```
<body> -> Main body from the Nuxt app
<Div> -> div to wrap components in
<body> -> Body that i added in the main Vue app file (its double)
</body>
</div>
</body>
```

If i look at the website of tailwind and inspect the website i see that there website uses the Tailwindcss classes on they main Body element.

**My question is where is this placed? or how can i access it.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using nuxt v3, you can add this to your `setup` method.

```
export default {
  setup () {
    useMeta({
      bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'dark:some-tailwind-class...'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: `useMeta` is deprecated as of today, use `useHead` instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to apply this change globally, inside `.nuxt.config.ts` you can add:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  //.. other fields
  app: {
    head: {
      bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'bg-gray-100',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta

Answer (score 2):

As of nuxt 3.8.1, useMeta is deprecated. Here is how I managed:

In pages/index.vue (could be done in app.vue; this project needed separate classes, modes etc. And I use nuxt/color-mode package):

```
const colorMode = useColorMode();

useHead({
  bodyAttrs: {
    class: [
      isScrolled.value ? "" : "banner-in-viewport",
      colorMode.value === "dark" ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light",
    ].join(" "),
  },
});
```